# Django post request looping on same route when using more than 1 replica on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and was trying to deploy a django app in a shared kubernetes cluster on Kubesail. I was pulling a docker image to run as a container on the cluster. Everything worked as expected until I increased the number of replicas to 2 instead of 1. When I made it 2, my post requests started looping. Meaning, If I'm trying to login into my application, I was again taken back to the login page despite entering the right credentials. Also no user session was created making my app completely inaccessible since all the routes require login. When I made the replicas revert back to 1, everything was normal and app was functioning as expected. Can someone explain why is it so? or can maybe tell what I did wrong?

Comment: What kind of command are you executing to scale up your application ?

Comment: I was scaling by applying an updated manifest defining the number of replicas I needed. You can see the YAML here https://www.codepile.net/pile/6A7J4wN9.